# Meaning of Import android.view.View

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have been following tutorials on how to make apps and I want to make a GUI purely in java in AndroidStudio. The am confused as to what packages are to be imported. Specifically, what does the following code mean?

import android.view.View

Answer (score 3):

View is a simple rectangle, the building  block of applications, as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) refers to it. Every Widget (TextViews, Buttons, and every other UI component) extends this class.

Show us your code and we can tell you why you need this class, but seriously, for this kind of question, just use [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Ask for help if you don't know how to use the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to the documentation, I just started developing and so I just need people to point me in the right direction. Thank you Gabriel!

Comment: That's okay, glad to help :)

Some more tips:

Always try to figure out the solution for yourself first by reading the documentation. It can be a daunting task scavenging through the docs, but it will help you a lot in the long run.

If you can't find a solution, search here in SO and Google for an answer! Often times, it's been answered.

And if you can't find the answer, ask here with details, code, what you did so far, etc.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot Gabriel. You really helped me out because I didn't know there was this documentation and so I tried to google for an answer and was unable too. And I'm for sure going to read through this documentation. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 2):

Views (and ViewGroups) are the basic building blocks of the Android UI. I believe you should go through this [introductory training article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) first to get familiar with the concept and its use.

> The graphical user interface for an Android app is built using a
>   hierarchy of View and ViewGroup objects. View objects are usually UI
>   widgets such as buttons or text fields. ViewGroup objects are
>   invisible view containers that define how the child views are laid
>   out, such as in a grid or a vertical list.